# What syntax do I use on status changes in printui.exe for printer settings via command line

Tags: batch-file, command-line, printing, cmd, rundll32

I need help, can someone help me set up a properly written settings-change request via command line or batch?

I have looked over the internet for command line help with writing a line to unpause a paused printer via batch script .  The resource at http://www.robvanderwoude.com/2kprintcontrol.php and at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/rundll32-printui both had helpful hints that this was possible, but none of them give examples or show the difference in changing a "nonstring" variable

When I search the printer for the settings, via the "/Xg" command, it returns the status state, but i can't edit it.

Currently i have this written as my change to set the printer to unpaused, but it simply says "The syntax of the command is incorrect"

```
Z:\>printui.exe /n "\\vm-net-1\IT_04" /Xs status -<Pause>
```

(The last piece reads < P a u s e > and it's getting truncated)

Can anyone help me understand how to use the printui utility better, or show me the proper way to syntax a status change?

Similarly, I believe that if I were able to change an attribute, that the process would be similar, but I can't get either to work right now.

Any answers are appreciated

UPDATE:

When I perform an "/Xg" command on the printer, I get some responses, listed below

- PrinterName: \vm-net-1\IT_04
- ShareName:   IT_04
- PortName:    IT_04
- DriverName:  Microsoft enhanced Point and Print compatibility driver
- Comment:
- Location:    Boulders Corporate Office
- SepFile:
- PrintProcessor:  winprint
- Datatype:    RAW
- Parameters:
- Attributes:
- Priority:    1
- DefaultPriority: 0
- StartTime:   0
- UntilTime:   0
- Status:
- ClientSideRender:    Enabled

And when I give it a "?" command for help, it returns these parameters for each field, and some examples, below

- rundll32 printui.dll,PrintUIEntry /Xs /n printer  [-|+]  [-|+] etc.
- key: PrinterName value:
- key: ShareName value:
- key: PortName value:
- key: DriverName value:
- key: Comment value:
- key: Location value:
- key: SepFile value:
- key: PrintProcessor value:
- key: Datatype value:
- key: Parameters value:
- key: Attributes value:
- key: Priority value:
- key: DefaultPriority value:
- key: StartTime value:
- key: UntilTime value:
- key: Status value:
- key: ClientSideRender value:

Examples:

- Pause printer:
- rundll32 printui.dll,PrintUIEntry /Xs /n "printer" status pause
- Set printer print direct to printer: 
  rundll32 printui.dll,PrintUIEntry /Xs /n "printer" attributes +direct
- Set printer to spool:
- rundll32 printui.dll,PrintUIEntry /Xs /n "printer" attributes -direct
- Set printer to hold mismatched documents and keep documents after they have printed:
- rundll32 printui.dll,PrintUIEntry /Xs /n "printer" attributes +EnableDevq attributes +KeepPrintedJobs
- Share printer:
- rundll32 printui.dll,PrintUIEntry /Xs /n "printer" sharename "Share" attributes +Shared
- Stop sharing printer:
  rundll32 printui.dll,PrintUIEntry /Xs /n "printer" attributes -Shared
- Set queue priority to 50:
  rundll32 printui.dll,PrintUIEntry /Xs /n "printer" priority 50
- Rename printer to Printer1:
  rundll32 printui.dll,PrintUIEntry /Xs /n "printer" printername "Printer1"

These examples show using Attribute, but I can't syntax a status change correctly, please help or give an example of a properly syntaxed status change, I would be very grateful

Comment: Tried `-^<Pause^>`?

Comment: The `<` and `>` characters are for redirection. @aschipfl is suggesting that you escape them so that they can be explicitly used. Another question might be why you need those characters in the status?

Comment: I was trying to mimic what was already there.  I didn't "dump" before what the return value currently was, and that will help, I think, in showing what I am trying to do:

Comment: I figured it out, .... and the examples helped, but I want to help others with a  similar issue:

printui.exe /Xs /n\\vm-net-1\IT_04 status resume 

This worked beautifully, I was trying to be too exact, and the command doesn't require removing a previous status (like the attribute one did)